# How we can handle SSL certificats of IE and chrome with selenium -webdriver?

Tags: webdriver, ssl-certificate, selenium-webdriver

How we can handle SSL certificats of IE and chrome with **selenium -webdriver**?

When i am running my script to open browser, which is having url with https:// i am getting popup which showing me certificate error.

I want to know how to handle that?

Comment: What do you mean with handle? Webdriver should ignore certificate errors by default.

Answer (score 0):

Add the correct certifcate to a chrome profile and load your profile using the following code

```
 DesiredCapabilities capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
  capabilities.setCapability("chrome.switches", Arrays.asList("--user-data-dir=/path/to/profile/directory"));
  WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(capabilities);
```

source: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver

For IE. it should be put in the default profile.